# Why do the vines change their spinning direction?

Tags: physiology, plant-physiology, biophysics

[image]

[image]

Look at the vines holding onto the lattice. The "vine springs" change their spinning direction in the middle. **Why? And how do they achieve this?**

(By the way, what's the name for this plant? Is is correct to call these "springs" vines?)

Edit: I notice that some vines fail to get in touch with the lattice, in such case they still change direction.

Comment: I believe what you are referring to are tendrils, the positively thigmotactic curly things that help some vines attach and climb. That sure looks like a cucumber to me, certainly a cucurbit anyway.